# Changing active definition query for multiple layers in group layer using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, definition-query, cartographic-information-model

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.x.

I'm trying to make a script to automate changing the definition query for multiple layers in a group layer in Pro. The definition query is essentially just using a project ID number ("TDS_WBS_CODE") to filter the data to a specific project.

The goal is to change the *active* definition query for multiple layers in a group layer and not have a list of unused queries.

My current code seems to fail at the "# Change the Definition query of target layers" comment.

```py
import arcpy

# access current pro project
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")

# access current map frame
m = aprx.activeMap

# access layers in TOC
lyrList = m.listLayers()

# list of target layer names
ADP_GIS_EDIT = ["ADP_GIS_EDIT\FiberSpliceEnclosure", "ADP_GIS_EDIT\AccessPoint", 
                "ADP_GIS_EDIT\FiberSplitter", "ADP_GIS_EDIT\Pole",
                "ADP_GIS_EDIT\FiberCable", "ADP_GIS_EDIT\Conduit", "ADP_GIS_EDIT\ServingArea"]

# loop that grabs "PortConnection" table
for m in aprx.listMaps():
    for tbl in m.listTables():
        if tbl.longName == "ADP_GIS_EDIT\PortConnection":
            print(tbl.longName)

# loop that grabs target features within "ADP_GIS_EDIT" group layer
for l in lyrList:
    if l.isGroupLayer:
        lyrs = l.listLayers()
        for lyr in lyrs:
            if lyr.longName in ADP_GIS_EDIT:
                # Change the Definition query of target layers
                cim_lyr = lyr.getDefinition("V2")
                if cim_lyr.featureTable.definitionFilterChoices:
                    cim_lyr.featureTable.definitionFilterChoices[0].definitionExpression = "TDS_WBS_CODE = 'TC-211606035'"
                    cim_lyr.featureTable.definitionExpression = None

                else:
                    cim_lyr.featureTable.definitionExpression = None

                    lyr.setDefinition(cim_lyr)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually set the definition query using the definitionQuery property:

```
lyr.definitionQuery = "TDS_WBS_CODE = 'TC-211606035'"
```

And clear the definitionQueries using:

```
lyr.updateDefinitionQueries([])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that worked!

```
import arcpy

# access current pro project
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")

# access current map frame
m = aprx.activeMap

# access layers in TOC
lyrList = m.listLayers()

# list of target layer names
ADP_GIS_EDIT = ["ADP_GIS_EDIT\FiberSpliceEnclosure", "ADP_GIS_EDIT\AccessPoint", "ADP_GIS_EDIT\FiberSplitter", "ADP_GIS_EDIT\Pole",
                "ADP_GIS_EDIT\FiberCable", "ADP_GIS_EDIT\Conduit", "ADP_GIS_EDIT\ServingArea"]

# CHANGE THIS ACCORDING TO PROJECT WBS CODE!!!
WBS = "TDS_WBS_CODE = 'TC-221608179'"

# loop that grabs "PortConnection" table
for m in aprx.listMaps():
    for tbl in m.listTables():
        if tbl.longName == "ADP_GIS_EDIT\PortConnection":
            # Change the Definition query of target table
            tbl.updateDefinitionQueries([])
            tbl.definitionQuery = WBS
        else:
            tbl.updateDefinitionQueries([])

# loop that grabs target features within "ADP_GIS_EDIT" group layer
for l in lyrList:
    if l.isGroupLayer:
        lyrs = l.listLayers()
        for lyr in lyrs:
            if lyr.longName in ADP_GIS_EDIT:
            # Change the Definition query of target layers
                lyr.updateDefinitionQueries([])
                lyr.definitionQuery = WBS
            else:
                lyr.updateDefinitionQueries([])
```